# Why resourceGenerator cannot attach file, generated in custom task upon assembly?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I am using SBT 0.13.16

I have a task, which generates a file, by running the main method from sources. This task calculates a path to a file and sends it to main method as an argument.

build.sbt:

```
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("generates file by executing main method")
myTask := Def.taskDyn {
    val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "fileFromTask.txt"
    val path = file.getAbsolutePath

    Def.task {
        (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $path").value
    }
}.value

assembly := (assembly dependsOn myTask).value

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
    val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "fileFromTask.txt"
    Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

Main.scala:

```
object Main extends App {
    val path = args(0)

    val file: Path = Paths.get( path )
    Files.createDirectories(file.getParent)
    Files.write(file, "Hi! I am a simple text file".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

I can't understand, why `sbt assembly` command generates file (I can see it in `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed`) but doesn't attach it in a `jar` file?

**BUT(!!!)**
Typing `sbt myTask assembly` in terminal, I can see generated file inside `jar`, as expected. Why is this so?

Comment: See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/258

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work (

Comment: I posted the link to show you that it's not supposed to work in the current version and it's a known issue. So you can participate in the discussion (on that issue) and add your usecase to motivate the developers to resolve it.